# what does overwrite existing source file mean while converting webapp to war file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, java-10

> what does export source file mean. will it make it more stable and should i choose optimize for a specific run time[image]

Comment: I've had Tomcat 9 working fine with Java 10 before.  Are you requiring the correct modules?

Comment: You mention tomcat 9, but your screenshot shows tomcat 6.0.29.

Comment: upgrade to tomcat 8 or 9

Comment: @sjahan i have both tomcat 9 and 7 installed i tried to switch the server to isolate if the issue is with tomcat or with jdk, so far im guessing the issue is with jdk 10

Answer (score 0):

- Click the question mark in the bottom left corner of the **WAR Export** screen shown in your post and a help panel opens.
- Click the link named *Search for WAR Export*.
- Click the link named *Exporting Web Archive (WAR) files*.
- The following text is shown, which addresses the questions you raised regarding **Export source files** and **Overwrite existing file**:

  > Optionally, supply WAR export Options, such as whether or not to
  >   include Java™ source files in the WAR, and whether to overwrite any
  >   existing resources during the export process. Source files are not
  >   usually included in a WAR file, because they are not necessary for the
  >   server to run the web application.
- The purpose of the **Overwrite existing file** checkbox is to prevent you from accidentally overwriting an existing WAR file: if the file specified in the **Destination** field already exists and the **Overwrite existing files** checkbox is not checked then the **Finish** button is disabled, and an error message is displayed.
- Regarding the **Optimize for a specific server runtime** checkbox, you should check it if you know which server the WAR file will be deployed on, in which case you will be forced to select the server from the drop list.